# Beamer: Inserting images

Tags: beamer, graphics, presentations

I'd like to add a first image to my latex presentation using the answer from [Image on beamer does not show](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424423/image-on-beamer-does-not-show).

The image and the .tex document are in the same folder. There are no spaces between words in the folder name. I get:

[image]

using

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\mode<presentation> 
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{presentation/image.png}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I also tried `{image.png}` and `{image}`.

Help will be appreciated!

EDIT:

My folder contains two images: `image.jpeg` and `image.png`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{image.png}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that is draft mode, either you have `[draft]` somewhere or you should have a missing file warning in the log

Comment: Do you still have the problem if you take out the `lmodern`, `\mode`, and `Warsaw` lines?  Do you have any messages in the log about not being able to find the image?  And please make sure that the code you post produces the output you claim it does.

Comment: but it will not say `.jpeg` if you used `.png` in the source, please show the output and log of the posted code

Comment: See edit. I removed lmodern, \mode and Warsaw. No messages in the log.

Comment: Sorry! I did not know that images are not displayed using the draft compile mode. It just solved the problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it have been solved by the user.

Comment: Sylvia, in the future please make sure that you use / provide the actual code that shows the output. It sounds like a simple recommendation but it is really important :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, it is revealed that the posted **MWE** was **not accurate**. In reality, the OP has the **`draft` mode of `beamer` active** which leads to the described behavior (as a feature).

[image]